# How to Unmarshal JSON into an interface in Go

Tags: json, go

I am trying to simultaneously unmarshal and strip fields from a number of different JSON responses into appropriate Go structs. To do this, I created a Wrappable interface that defines the Unwrap method (which strips the appropriate fields) and pass that interface to the code that unmarshals and unwraps. It looks like the following example (also at http://play.golang.org/p/fUGveHwiz9):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
    B string `json:"b"`
}

type DataWrapper struct {
    Elements []Data `json:"elems"`
}

type Wrapper interface {
    Unwrap() []interface{}
}

func (dw DataWrapper) Unwrap() []interface{} {
    result := make([]interface{}, len(dw.Elements))
    for i := range dw.Elements {
        result[i] = dw.Elements[i]
    }
    return result
}

func unmarshalAndUnwrap(data []byte, wrapper Wrapper) []interface{} {
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &wrapper)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return wrapper.Unwrap()
}

func main() {
    data := `{"elems": [{"a": "data", "b": "data"}, {"a": "data", "b": "data"}]}`
    res := unmarshalAndUnwrap([]byte(data), DataWrapper{})
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

However, when I run the code, Go panics with the following error:

```
panic: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.Wrapper
```

It seems the unmarshaller doesn't want to be passed a pointer to an interface. I am somewhat surprised by this given that I can get at the underlying type and fields using the reflect package within the unmarshalAndUnwrap method. Can anyone provide insight into this problem and how I might work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, passing a non-pointer fails. Why are you trying to do this anyway?

Replace

`res := unmarshalAndUnwrap([]byte(data), DataWrapper{})`

by

`res := unmarshalAndUnwrap([]byte(data), &DataWrapper{})`

It should do the trick and it avoid unnecessary copy.

This error should help you understand: http://play.golang.org/p/jXxCxPQDOw

Comment: Ultimately, this is what I ended up doing. For other reasons not present in the example code, it made more sense *not* to pass a pointer, but changing it to pointer *did* work. It still bothers me that the JSON unmarshaller can't operate on interface values, because the underlying concrete type is available through the reflect package (used by the json package).

Comment: This helped me as well. I think this happens because, if you store a non-pointer object (like the DataWrapper{}) inside an interface, the "reflect" or type assertion can only get a duplicated object of the original non-pointer object, and thus couldn't assign values to your original one. However, if you save a pointer inside it (like the &DataWrapper{}), golang will be able to find the correct memory addresses and finally update those values.